# How can I force i3 to start the application where I started it?

Tags: i3

The application I open in i3 should stay, where I started it and not open at the workspace, I am at the moment. How am I able to achieve that?

example for clarification:
I open chromium  on workspace 1 and then switch to workspace 2 to open another application. What happens is, that chromium starts at workspace 2.